# PHP HTML DOM Parser Select alt from img tag

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I am trying to pull only the alt value from the img tag using the simple php html dom parser.  I cannot seem to get it to just pull the alt tag.  Here is what I am using:

```
foreach($html->find('ul.sellerInformation img', 0) as $element) {    
    $ret['SoldBy'] = $element->alt; 
}
```

It works and pulls the entire image tag if I use:

```
$ret['SoldBy'] = $html->find('ul.sellerInformation img', 0)->outertext;
```

But all I really want is the information in the alt tag.

I am trying to pull from html at the Amazon offer listing page at: http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B001H8QHG0

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're tying to get the value of the `alt` attribute here not the `alt` tag.
If so, you can use the `getAttribute` method.

```
$altValue = $html->find('ul.sellerInformation img', 0)->getAttribute('alt');
```